# Creating chart from datagridview C#

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview

Good day,

i have a little problem. I'm trying to make chart from dataGridView so i wrote short code.

private void create_graphs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Chart chart1 = new Chart();

        chart1.Series[0] = new Series();
        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);

    }
```

Syntax without error. Problem is, when i start it, it says:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 8.7.2017 18:07:

So thanks for your help. I eddited a code and now looks like this:

```
        ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

        chart1.Series.Add(new Series());

        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

And its working. Creates a graph but now i need to make that graph, well bigger. This is output image... I don't know how to put image here so at least link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znkOf.jpg

Thing is, i have 93 items in my Column so i need that chart to show all 12 months or 13 months... from 1.1.2008 to 1.1.2009

Comment: I can't see what library your ´Chart´ type is from, please add this information.
Just by guessing, I would assume that the second line of your code should look like this:
´chart1.Series.Add( new Series() );´

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

Comment: 1) you will need to add a ChartArea. 2) you should add a new Series using chart.Series.Add() 3) It ususally is easier to bind the the Points of a Series.  4) Which line throws? I see no `item` in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It worked... now i made eddit with different problem if you don't mind :)

Comment: You mean the datasource/dgv have 93 rows? They ought to show all, squezed into the size of the chart. You can make it wider if you want, but the labels will not be able to accomodate too many entries on the x-axis. Try `chart1.Width = 2000` for test..

Comment: Yes chart1.Size(500,500) for example makes that chart bigger but what i want... My data have 93 rows but its all spread across one year so 93 items in 12 months. I want my X axis to show me 12 X points instead of 5 like on the picture... so 1.1.2008 1.2.2008, 1.3.2008... 1.1.2009

Comment: You can set the Interval of the x-axis. That is: Provided you have DateTimes in your datasource. You may also want to set the IntervalType, maybe to month

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. This did the trick:

chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1;