# Creating a chart from bound and unbound datagridview columns

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview, devexpress

I am trying to create a chart based on my data grid using DevExpress controls. My data grid contains bound and unbound columns, I have successfully been apple to display the bound columns in the chart, but unfortunately not been able to do the same for the unbound columns. The unbound columns display the running total of the bounds columns and I want to plot both in the same chart. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

I have read the following links but still unsuccessful:
[Creating chart from datagridview C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542298/creating-chart-from-datagridview-c-sharp)
[Get data from DataGridView to Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005460/get-data-from-datagridview-to-chart)

So, how to bind data from datagridview with a chart?

Here is my code:

```
private void ChartData() {
    //binds the chart control to the grid control datasource
    ProdchartControl.DataSource = ProdgridControl.DataSource;
    //assign specific series to unbound columns
    ProdchartControl.Series[" Cum prodA"].ArgumentDataMember = "Prod_Date";
    ProdchartControl.Series["A Prod Cumprod"].ValueDataMembers.AddRange("ACumProd");
}
```

Here is my datagrid datasource:

```
void DisplayProd() { 
    ProdBL prodbls = new ProdBL(); 
    ProdgridControl.DataSource = prodbls.ListProd();
}
```

regards.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task, create separate Series items linked to the ControlRowSource component and use the GetRowCellValue method to get data from unbound columns. You will find a sample project illustrating this approach in the [How to display data from an unbound column displayed in the grid control](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t707931/how-to-display-data-from-an-unbound-column-displayed-in-the-grid-control) thread.